# Network wireless USB dongle

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, usb-2

Here in Panama City, Panama they have a telephone company which sells wireless USB adapters for laptops and desktops.  Can other computers use the same connection with a wireless router and a USB dongle to share the internet wireless USB adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the wireless router, but you don't need it.  You don't mention which Operating System you're using, but since the odds are good that you're running Windows, look into "Internet Connection Sharing".

You set that up on the computer with the dongle, share it over that computer's wifi in "ad-hoc" mode and other computers can connect and use it.